# Regex: capture repeated sequences with extra part of theses at the end

Tags: regex

This regular expression : `([-/*.]{2,})\1{2,}` matches any sequences of theses characters repeated at least 3 times : `-`, `/`, `*` and `.`

For example:

```
-/-/-/-/
**.**.**.
---**---**---**
```

I would like to also match the first part of the sequence if added at the end, for example:

```
-/-/-/-/-
**.**.**.**
---**---**---**---
```

The improved regex would matches the last part of theses examples. Here `-`, `---` and `**` (mine doesn't).

If anyone loving regex have a clue, thanks :)

For testing purpose, regular expressions that should match entirely :

```
-/-/-/-/-
**.**.**.**
---**---**---**---
./*./*./*
.-.-.-.-.
**//**//**//**
-----/-----/-----/-----
```

Comment: You are repeating a capture group that can consist of mixed chars `[-/*.]` How would you know that the last part in `-----/-----/-----/-----` is `-----` How would you know what the last part is here? `******-/*`

Answer (score 0):

`(?<whole>(?<pattern>(?<char>.)\k<char>*)(.)+)\k<whole>{2,}\k<pattern>?`

[Here is the regex101 demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/ulmPtp/1) for a better explanation of each individual unit.

Comment if any issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the attempt but maybe I should have been more explicit. The regular expression should be able to match any combination of repeated sequences. Like `.-.-.-` `***//***//***//` And that's all the difficulty of the question :)

Comment: Interesting, will have a tinker and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Just updated answer to match requirements.

Comment: sorry for the time you spent on this new attempt but it doesn't match any combination of the repeated sequences like I mentioned. 

For example : https://pastebin.com/50auUnpg

Comment: Are you sure, seems to succesfully match all those samples here: https://regex101.com/r/j0Tmfh/1

Comment: ah, I put the wrong link in the answer, check now. The correctp regex is in the answer regardless.